# Unable to SSH into GCP VM instance after updating python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I recently updated the stock python 3.5 to python 3.8 on my linux VM(ubuntu 16.04) and now i am unable to SSH into the instance. After checking that all firewall rules and permissions are set as expected i looked into the "Serial port 1 console" and found that the default startup scripts of the VM are failing due to some missing python modules. This is likely due to my python3 upgrade. How can i fix this? The snapshot of the error logs is attached for reference
[image]

Comment: Edit your question with the exact steps that caused this problem. Normally, a Python package update will not leave your system with missing dependencies. Either you forced the update, updated in a non-supported manner, or you have identified a bug. I cannot tell from a partial screenshot.

Comment: Also, GCP VMs rely on Python for authentication bits (adding users and their SSH keys from metadata). If those scripts cannot run because you upgraded Python then you won't be able to SSH (and, as you have noted from the console, other stuff will fail as well).

Comment: @jhon i think you are right ... the python3.8 upgrade wasn't a smooth upgrade and i had to do a few manual package updates to make it work... which might have caused the issue..... anyways luckily i had a snapshot of the disk .. so that saved the day.